# Json Parse - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON Javascript escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180462/json-javascript-escape)

I tested my JSON on jsonlint and it is valid but i got an error when i try to parse it,

Here is my JSON and the function to parse :

```
var listVideo = JSON.parse('[{"blobkey":"AMIfv94kAyQziQMwOLOrjqBK-MxqQqeBK96dS4Fh5DgR-yIW4jHq3luUwNvGpTOfUD9qXlFNQUjYXGkYrmmV8_mrZKbiK6MAUJwuSQkhxw-qaQZLVHcpb19gWUEpxiAzh1z4fMyBBBb4","id":41,"linkId":"","price":500,"description":"This building video showcases a luxury building located in the Financial District. It includes shots of the building exterior, lobby, and outdoor areas. A sample apartment is also showcased.","name":"Apartment Building","reel":false,"type":0,"approximateTime":3},{"blobkey":"AMIfv95JWHFzuK0BYadlQM61VQyOuGE5rT-buMuFLmXk7Dj4GFE_AAtniI4nuL5kD94O6K7zor6RvPcnsCKcTbx4KM8oN0apq0BHS5rTlUs4-Xww9MvdVvvANGOVovyrzlAswcI6vFZ6","id":42,"linkId":"","price":0,"description":"My reel showcases snippets from past video projects. It should communicate my personal aesthetic when shooting and editing. ","name":"My Reel","reel":true,"type":0,"approximateTime":0},{"blobkey":"AMIfv97pnf1y8Aek4RCX8c2uaAsLVc91o00JoP5l2Fk7XiWKCxCVBCAxPmMjjV5aUfgmAI2tadxyCfns6FIcQR12Lv-JaTdyJjIYYIUVyWy8iI3eBtKkJ9cxikXaPsprYGt642-U379A","id":43,"linkId":"","price":700,"description":"The Bean is a neighborhood coffee shop located in the East Village. In addition to capturing the physical space, this video contains commentary from regular customers.","name":"Coffee Shop Video","reel":false,"type":0,"approximateTime":3},{"blobkey":"AMIfv96EUXtcTd166Lg0MqeL7UA6zWYGA7AVkw1ltGf088xwkjWXDvhaG3M6rBsf6Jwz6MGTCQkhDJiVRSc-EyMIebt0SVzR9eXNI879sTATNQPvXsp0c3xL4yRJ6WQ2MfT90XMwm8pC","id":44,"linkId":"","price":1500,"description":"This video is a client testimonial for Yesware, an email marketing software company. It contains comments from three Yesware customers. ","name":"Client Testimonial","reel":false,"type":0,"approximateTime":14},{"blobkey":"AMIfv97QwJlN6K3GebdJQASXRRKcrxOjHnZcEocZ_Urab5539_jc6AeuGqDrj6jCv4RVIJcyNeb0b3-5odxGjlLqU76yPPGq8P6Au3AS30arXsy3PWKhniX6y4p4CLAIPv7XJdA0_mxM","id":45,"linkId":"","price":500,"description":"Bond New York, a Manhattan real estate agency, hosts an art event each month. This video recap includes testimonials by attendees as well as b-roll. ","name":"Event Sample","reel":false,"type":0,"approximateTime":4},{"blobkey":"AMIfv96_narMmT6tdnhD5KkVJ_oJ0wZpqGGTvM15xc9tpFlHLTd6vjLLfLw0Ak5awfc5Lge9_zK0W5w1tHktmc8mftQdbPIgXlyPKE02y1X4lGF0bkRtRhX6h7834R0yLnsEluIDwvgu","id":46,"linkId":"","price":1000,"description":"A roundtable discussion with StreetEasy correspondent, Sofia, and John Gomes/Fredrik Eklund of Prudential Douglas Elliman. The pair are established agents in the luxury market -- and you may recognize Fredrik from the Bravo TV series Million Dollar Listing. Watch the video for an animated discussion of contract activity and median prices.","name":"StreetEasy Roundtable Discussion","reel":false,"type":0,"approximateTime":4},{"blobkey":"AMIfv95HNN_nA11jaNdleFkrLfIVlMJvEvLu8kRrUaybhG1VKAj6f2SUZBvdCX7PN_xuScXzpVFE8ci77pJtcXh-D9qoEjgkJ9sK6MAu9M8mgxPg5p43UXcJ1VoyPE23YnOfmWvyCE03","id":47,"linkId":"","price":500,"description":"Client testimonial shot for Clevertech, a software development company. The subject is Amy Epstein, the managing director at ABI, a public relations firm.","name":"Client Testimonial ","reel":false,"type":0,"approximateTime":3},{"blobkey":"AMIfv95tEXCSJtLP1w_MWnmx21L2OlxQGap4PXIc7aqZbbnm0ZMOwiNSbECrXx2nuscDrZyd4Joq6eiRUFBZxKACpCVGQVvLpLfjyVGRHvTUFOYtk9ZnFTzM_GVukKDX3-0dESm5JJMl","id":48,"linkId":"","price":400,"description":"The Bean, a coffee shop located in the East Village, offers a frozen coffee beverage called the Frozen Mona Lisa. This video shows an employee making one from start to finish.","name":"Product Video: Frozen Mona Lisa","reel":false,"type":0,"approximateTime":2},{"blobkey":"AMIfv97s4c7JQtKM147oJzHZFNtFqIBhZARUCxZdrui7xI1RXUfolrRchfRhzCERdcgVtid5_-dE75jnKBHHh3CtBSRDFnnhlQjMpHRVkAhA5kVH0ExezSkrdi0GoPClfHLvaGrFo8gW","id":49,"linkId":"","price":300,"description":"An apartment video shot for East Village Apartments. It includes shots of the building exterior as well as a comprehensive look in the interior: bedroom, bathroom, living room, kitchen etc\u2026","name":"Apartment Video","reel":false,"type":0,"approximateTime":3},{"blobkey":"AMIfv94YHo2Xx_3LVYhvngnm_cSEoLu-8btAgCl57YYrcqHtMbrdAFvdzq9D5fE525xkK5tv0E_e_7zqNU8r_e_DMnFcA_iRBKLdKuHKpp74t8fJrTatTBlLFKPjIGcDcmjiIVx4cpy5","id":53,"linkId":"","price":1000,"description":"","name":"Coffee Shop Overview: The Bean","reel":false,"type":0,"approximateTime":5},{"id":59,"linkId":"SAAIFzlgOhQ","price":0,"description":"dzdzdzdzdzdzdz","name":"zdzddzdzdzdz","reel":false,"type":1,"approximateTime":0},{"id":60,"linkId":"dGghkjpNCQ8","price":2,"description":"effefe","name":"effefe","reel":false,"type":1,"approximateTime":2},{"id":63,"linkId":"1q-ZqbK2g3Y","price":400,"description":"Created for \"The Young Republican\" campaign. Commissioned by the republican activist Geoff Harbough.","name":"3D Motion graphics sample","reel":false,"type":1,"approximateTime":2},{"id":64,"linkId":"kiGkV1_1V3U","price":450,"description":"This unofficial video was edited and presented to the artist Nadia Kay as a one of the broadcast versions. Copyright of Silver Curve Records.","name":"Music video edit sample","reel":false,"type":1,"approximateTime":5}]');
```

I got this error : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T"

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C4jh5/

Comment: Why do you have string literals with JSON in your JavaScript code?

Comment: Your JSON is not formatted very reader-friendly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should escape quotes correctly:

```
... ,"description":"Created for \\"The Young Republican\\" campaign. Commissioned by the republican activist Geoff Harbough.", ...
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/C4jh5/1/

Comment: Good one, I was removing objects 1 by 1 to find this one.. was going to post the exact same thing :)

Comment: @Vega I did the same, but 2 by 2 :D

Comment: @VisioN , just wondering why a single backslash won't work .. \"text\".. This seems to work in some places

Comment: @Sushanth-- it's because javascript itself is also parsing the backslashes in this string. You need to escape the backslash so that it is actually passed into JSON.parse, which then uses that backslash to know that the doublequote following it is part of the string.

Comment: @VisioN is right, but a way better solution is to leave the code the JSON the way you have it and remove the `JSON.parse`. You've got an object literal there, just assign it.