# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < for list 1 of php (<?php)

Tags: php, javascript, html, proxy

I tired using the proxy solution in

[Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683530/origin-http-localhost-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

and on the file proxy.php I have

```
<?php
// File Name: proxy.php
if (!isset($_GET['url'])) die();
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$url = 'http://' . str_replace('http://', '', $url); // Avoid accessing the file system
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

In main I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script src="proxy.php"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-                1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
url:"proxy.php?url=theurlofmyapi",
type:'GET',
dataType:"json",
success:function(data){console.log(data.results.result[1].category);}
});</script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="header"> 
<h1>Upcoming Movies</h1> 
</div> 
<ul id= "data" data-role="listview">
<li><img src="http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/17/20/11172082_mob.jpg"         class="ui-li-thumb"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">Warning</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">hot</p>                           </li>
<li><a href="javascript:alert('hi')">Audi</a></li>
<li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
</ul></body></html>
```

Now I call main.html in my localhost in Google chrome and the console says error on first line of php. I'm not sure what the problem is. The error message is:
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351478/json-parse-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-t

Comment: I saw previous questions like this. I think mine is different because the error is at the first line of my php code. the<?php is a syntax error? Its almost like <?php is not being recognized...

Comment: I don't see that part in your code?

Comment: The first line in proxy.php which i pasted as the first code section in my questions. 
The first line is <?php
I think the console is telling me it doesn't recognize the < portion of it

Comment: Include your `proxy.php` code as well.

Comment: The first code snippit is my proxy.php code.

Comment: may be you have a special caracter before <?php try encoding your file to utf8

Comment: i tried re-writing the code from a scratch generated php file from eclipse. The result is still the same. I still have the error

Comment: A very good discussion which can help you is here http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Uj6DitMGK1A Do check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this line from your html:

```
<script src="proxy.php"></script>
```

Comment: Yup this was the right solution, that line copied my code in there a second time. Since proxy.php didn't have a closing tag, there was an error