# Ajax $array post method results in error sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a huge problem for weeks now, I have to say I don't have a lot of AJAX experience, so it can be an easy problem for someone I hope.

I have an AJAX script, which is used for importing a JSON array from a PHP file and it works fine like 80% of the time.

But sometimes for like 1 hour a day the `$ajax` part results in an error.

This is my script:

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/php/home.php', //Url to .php file
        data: {'data': data}, //Parameter to pass to the .php file, i.e. different query IDs, etc.. - DO NOT REMOVE!
        type: 'POST', //Set Ajax to 'POST' type
        dataType: 'json', //Tell the return data type to the JS engine
        timeout: 10000,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) { //If the query fails:
            alert('BETA - The cause of error is: ' + xhr.responseText); //v1.1 - display the cause of the error 
        },
        success: function(output) { //If query is successful:
            drawChart(output); //Call the chart drawing function, pass the Ajax result as parameter
        }
    });
}
```

The referenced PHP file works fine always.
This even got stranger, because I tried to find the cause and the error function gave me the following:

```
status: error , error: empty , xhr.responsetext: empty
```

So as I said it works usually, and separate JS files result in an error for the same period of time.

I have already tried the following:

- tried with different browsers;
- tried to implement `noconflicts()` before the function;
- contacted my hosting and asked if I get somehow limited, not and they don't see any errors in logs either;
- tried to debug and it goes to the error;

Do you have any idea what can cause the problem?
Even a hint could help me a lot! Huge thanks to everyone!

Comment: For me such errors occurs, when a running Ajax call is cancelled because of a new request or my local network is offline when resuming from standby (I'm running a virtual machine on my laptop).

Comment: Have you investigated if it is because of invalid json characters? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180462/json-javascript-escape

Comment: why your are using `timeout:10000` cause if your server will take more time then defenetly it kills your ajax request.

Comment: what you are fetching through `/php/home.php` ?

Comment: hows you using `getData()` function? Are you using pooling?

Comment: I added the timeout to solve the issue, but it did not work, so i will delete that now.

Comment: I am getting the data in the following format: [[" Time"," item1", "item2"],[5,10,1],[4,8,2],[3,6,4],[2,4,1]] this is the format, but the data is changing in it, but it stays the same format.

Comment: Also the script runs on a VPS, which had 100% uptime in the problematic periods

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me, the problem is solved now, I found the answer in another stackoverflow discussion and just implemented it before posting the code here (so sorry for misleading you) Actually for everyone having the same problem: The answer was to remove the domain name from the PHP URL, this caused the sometimes not working error. Thanks again everyone for help! Plz close this thread.